# get start and end day of week by year, month and week number

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

**Goal**

I want to get start day and end day by giving year, month and week number.
I'm trying to use momentjs as it was already in my dependency.

**Work I've done**

It seems it's not possible if I set .month(monthInNumber) as I don't get Monday and it messes up so what I've done is naive way which is not working = 4*month and set it up as week.

```
getStartDateByWeekAndYear = function(week, year, month) {
    return moment().day("Monday").year(year).week((4*month)+(week)).toDate();
};
```

For last day(I want Satruday as last day and not Sunday)

```
getLastDateByWeekAndYear = function(week, year, month) {
    return moment().day("Saturday").year(year).week((4*month)+(week)).toDate();
};
```

I also tried couple of solutions but it seems it's not working If I try to implement same in my functions above.

**Expected Output**

```
getStartDateByWeekAndYear(2, 2019, 6)
```

I should get Monday, 3 June 2019 which is Today's date

```
getEndDateByWeekAndYear(2, 2019, 6)
```

I should get Saturday, 8 June 2019 which is this week's Saturday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that start of a given month/year using [`moment({Object})`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/) and then get your desired week, by adding weeks using [`add()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/).

Here a live sample:

```js
const getStartDateByWeekAndYear = function(week, year, month) {
    return moment({y: year, M: month-1, d: 1})
      .add(week-1, 'w').day("Monday").toDate();
};

const getEndDateByWeekAndYear = function(week, year, month) {
    return moment({y: year, M: month-1, d: 1})
      .add(week-1, 'w').day("Saturday").toDate();
}

console.log( getStartDateByWeekAndYear(2, 2019, 6) );
console.log( getEndDateByWeekAndYear(2, 2019, 6)  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, very much. This is perfect and exactly what I wanted. Seems I was messing up with .week().